# How does command 'KEYS *' impact redis memory management?

Tags: python-3.x, redis, redis-cluster

I got the below error when I ran KEYS * on a highly usable Redis server.

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1394, in set
return self.execute_command('SET', *pieces)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/base.py", line 210, in call_if_sampling
return self.call(module, method, wrapped, instance, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/redis.py", line 66, in call
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 755, in execute_command
return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 768, in parse_response
response = connection.read_response()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 638, in read_response
raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.

Answer (score 1):

`keys *` will scan all keys in Redis database, put all the keys into a in-memory list, and then build the response for the command.

If you have a huge amount of keys, it will impact the memory usage significantly, which may cause OOM exception.